# Fill array with multiple threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, multicore

I have the following code of filling an array with multiple threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_ITEMS 67108864
#define LINES_PER_THREAD 8388608
#define THREADS 8
static int *array;

static pthread_t pids[THREADS];
static int args[THREADS];


static void init_array_line(int *line) {
    int i, max;
    i = *line;
    max = i + LINES_PER_THREAD;
    for (i; i < max; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % 10000 + 1;
}

static void init_array() {
     int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        args[i]=i* LINES_PER_THREAD;
        pthread_create(pids + i, NULL, &init_array_line, args + i);;
    }
}

static wait_all() {
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(pids[i], NULL);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    array = (int *)malloc(MAX_ITEMS * sizeof(int));
    init_array();
    wait_all();
}
```

I am giving each thread 1/8 of the array to fill `LINES_PER_THREAD`, but it seems that it takes longer than filling it normally. Any suggestions why might this be?

Comment: Is there any reason why you like the keyword `static` so much? Anyway - you do not need to cast `malloc` in C - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: "it seems that it takes longer than filling it normally". How do you measure?

Comment: I am compiling with: gcc q.c -lm -std=c99 -o q -lpthread  and measuring with time ./q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the main bottleneck would the calls to `rand()`. `rand()` isn't required to be thread-safe. So, it can't be safely used in a multi-threaded program when multiple threads could call `rand()` concurrently. But the Glibc implementation uses an internal lock to protect against such uses. This effectively serializes the call to `rand()` in all threads and thus severely affecting the multi-threaded nature of your program. Instead use [`rand_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) which doesn't need to maintain any internal state (because the caller(s) do) and can at least solve this aspect of your problem.

In general, if the threads don't do sufficient work then the thread creation/synchronization overhead can outdo the concurrency that could be available on multi-core systems using threads.

Comment: This works. Now the execution time is 5sec insted of 25sec. Thank you.

Comment: But still, if i run the program normally without any threads it takes 1.2 sec but with threads it takes 5 sec. So like you said, the problem is not big enough for 8 threads.

Comment: You might want to examine your code some more. I translated the program into Ada and my time for 8 tasks is 0.37 seconds while my time for the sequential version is 2.01 seconds.

Comment: @JimRogers I did some more testing and wait_all() function takes 4,7 seconds. That is the reason why parallel version takes more time than sequential one for me. Perhaps any ideas how to resolve that? I am quite new to parallel programing.

Comment: @io16 The Ada language does not have a direct equivalent to the wait_all() function, so I wrote my own. Testing shows that my version, for Ada, takes 0,49 seconds and the overall run takes 0,89 seconds. I was too late to edit my previous timings. Setting up the Ada tasks, which are equivalent to threads, took 0,37 seconds. I have the program report its timing as its output.